# Java 8 how to iterate over a nested list of objects

Tags: java

I am new to Java 8 and i have a response object which has a list of detail object and the detail object contains a list of reason object where the reason object has a reason code. I am trying to iterate to the reason object from the response object and search if there is any reason code equal to a given key. Could you please help in how to do that in java 8, with minimum complexity. Below is sample way in java 7 not the best approach thou.

```
 if(response != null && CollectionsUtil.isNotEmpty(response.getDetails())) {

            List<Detail> details = response.getDetails();
            for(Detail det : details) {
                if(CollectionsUtil.isNotEmpty(det.getReasons())) {                  
                    for(Reason reason: det.getReasons()) {
                        if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC", reason.getReasonCode())) {
                            ///////////call an external method
                        }
                    }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you are looking for an operation called `flatMap`

Comment: And what does the external method need? Does it need the detail instance?

Comment: The tests checking if the collections are empty are useless. Just loop through the collections. If they're empty the loop won't execute, whether or not you test if it's empty.

Comment: I am passing the key to the external method if it is present, and the null check is to avoid null pointer exception, my question is how to do such in Java 8

Comment: @JBNizet `CollectionUtil.isNotEmpty() ` might perform a null check.

Comment: @daniu If so, the first thing to do would be to fix the design: a collection shouldn't be null, ever. That should be an invariant of the class.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree. A check still might have its place though in some cases, eg Jaxb deserialization initializes collection members to null.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `getReasons()` returns a `List`:

```
details.stream().
     flatMap(e -> e.getReasons().stream()).
     filter(reason -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC", reason.getReasonCode())).
     forEach(System.out::println);
```

Where you would replace `System.out::println` with the method you wanted to invoke. Also note that I removed the check of `CollectionsUtil.isNotEmpty(det.getReasons())`, as if the list is empty, it won't make any difference

Comment: I was working on a very similar answer.  If OP is just looking to see if there is any matching key to pass along, the `filter` and `forEach` could be replaced with a `anyMatch` call inside the if statement.

Comment: May I know the reason to use `flatMap`? I think `map(r->r.getDetails()).map(d->d.getReasons())` also works?

Comment: @LunaticJape Yes both ways should work. However `flatMap` flattens it to a `Stream` of objects, as opposed to a `Stream` of `Stream` of objects

Comment: @GBlodgett In this case it should be `Stream<List>` if I use map instead flatmap, right?